Dual citizenship French Australian, different names on passports
I have dual citizenship French and Australian, however my French passport shows my maiden name followed by "spouse" married name, my Australian passport only shows my married name.
I am currently in France going to Vietnam on 2ways ticket, then I must go to Australia then back to Vietnam. I was thinking to purchase my ticket to go to Australia while I am in Vietnam. can I buy a 2ways ticket from Vietnam as I planned to go back there spend more time?
(I know french passport don't need visa to enter vetnam but Australian passport do).
Which passport do I use between France Vietnan Australia please, as tickets must match passports. Thank you

This question is similar to: What do I travel with on a dual citizenship situation when names are different?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. You might also review this prior question and answer.

This question is also relevant to your situation.
